# How to transfer files (PDF, images etc) in JSON?

Tags: java, json, spring

How to send file from my backend project to my frontend using `JSONObject` in Java so I want to know if it is possible and how? (I'm using Spring framework)

Comment: You can base64 encode the file bytes and then send them as string.

Comment: after encoding can I  decode it to retrieve the original file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly send bytes of the file or you can convert file into stream and then send.